# Any WorkAround For Java ResultSet Limitation

Tags: java, jdbc, database-migration

I am doing a database migration work. I have to copy a database in MSSQL to MySql database. It was possible to come up with a small java utility to copy table stucture from MSSQL to MySql Database. Now i have to copy all data from MSSQL to MySql. I tried using resultset in java to obtain all data from a table but then it could only fetch a small part of data. Is there any alternate solution to get all data from table to resultset or to some other similar structure which i could possibly use, to insert the same data into mysql Db. There are more than 25,00,000 records for a table.

Comment: There is no such limitation in JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JDBC result set should in principle allow you to iterate the entirity of a large query result.

However going via Java may not be the most efficient approach. Bulk export to a file and bulk import may be the way to go. It appears that MS has a [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) utility that may do the export.

Comment: Thanx djna,
Bulk export to a file from mssql?? Can u elaborate a bit.
Thanks in advance again :)

Comment: Some database vendors have utlities for exporting and importing data. It appears that MS do. I don't know how readily that export can be imported to MYSQL, but once you have a file to play with I'd expect any required transforms to be quite easy.

Comment: the tool in mssql is called bcp

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve a database migration like you describe is to use and ETL Tool - there's a good overview of ETL here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

There's no reason why you wouldn't be able to do this with JDBC and so if you are set on rolling your own please elaborate on 'could only fetch a small part of data':

- what is the query you are running?
- are you getting an exception?
- which JDBC driver are you using to connect to MS-SQL?

Comment: hi Nick,
Thank you for your response.
I know that ideally resultset should pick up all data from database,but then its not working for me.

* The query which I am trying to run is "SELECT * FROM <TableName>"
* I am not getting any exception while executing the query
* the jdbc driver is microsoft jdbc SQL Server Driver

Comment: Hi Richie - the MS JDBC driver isn't that good (some might say intentionally).  Try using the TDS driver - http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html